# How can we be sure what the first day of the month was 2000 years ago and how can we determine which years were leap years?

Tags: calendar

I have a question that hopefully someone can answer.

I am aware that most Christians disagree which year Jesus died. Heck, they not only disagree on which day he died but which year he was born. They also disagree with each other about long his ministry was.

People have used astronomical calculations to arrive at certain new moon dates and full moon dates in an attempt to arrive at a year Jesus died. Historically, we know that Pilate was the prefect of Judea from 26 CE to 36 so that narrows it down somewhat. We also have two conflicting dates in which to reckon Tiberius Caesar's 15th year. Whatever that year may be, we know John the Baptist began his ministry that year. Whatever part of Tiberius' 15th year may be we do not know with certainty. John could have begun his ministry in the first part of Tiberius' 15th year, the middle, or the end of Tiberius' year. We don't know for sure how long into John's ministry Jesus came along to be baptized. If John began his ministry during the latter half of Tiberius' 15th year, then it is possible that Jesus began his ministry during Tiberius' 16th year. Then came 40 days in the wilderness followed by the beginning of Jesus' ministry. We know from the book of Luke that Jesus was "about" 30 years old when he was baptized by John. Since the first two chapters in Luke reveal John and Jesus were almost the same age (six months apart) we can pretty well guess Jesus began his ministry sometime during the 16th year of Tiberius's reign.

Depending on which year was correctly called Tiberius' 15th year reign, Jesus could have begun his ministry sometime between 27 and 29 CE. What year he was born I cannot determine with certainty but the bottom line is he was "about" 30 when he was baptized. Could that mean he was 29 going on 30 or he was just turned 31? Now, how long did his ministry last? Some claim one year, others two years and some 3 1/2 years. These estimates attempt to take a guess at how many Passovers Jesus celebrated in his ministry. I know of one who believes Jesus' ministry lasted five years and his crucifixion occurred in 34 CE.

However, there is a problem. We can now, in our modern time, correctly calculate new moon dates back to Jesus' time and can guess which day was the first month of the Jewish year, the month of Passover. The Jews have calculated in advance every new moon for the next thousand years and have calculated new moons going back in time for thousands of years. The calculations are highly accurate and even calculate for leap years, about seven every 19 years, However, in Jesus's day, they did not use calculations. They did not begin on the new moon, but on the observance of the thin crescent of the moon in the western sky a day or two after the actual new moon. It was done when trained observers would spot the crescent and report it to the Sanhedrin in Jerusalem. In Jesus's day a month could have 29 or 30 days, no more. Therefore, if the crescent still wasn't spotted at the end of the 30th day, the next month would begin whether the crescent was spotted or not.

Another thing is modern Jewish calculations calculate leap years automatically. In Jesus's day when the barley harvest would not be ready by Nisan 15 the Jews would add a leap month and call it Adar II. My question is, how do we determine the year Jesus died if we know he died on a Friday, Nisan 14 and was raised from the dead Sunday, Nisan 16? Some calculations place Jesus's death on a Wednesday, Nisan 14 in 34 CE. I think in this scenario the Julian calendar the day of Jesus death was March 24 that year. That would mean the sighting of the new moon would be on Nisan 10. But since the new moon that preceded the spring equinox in 34 CE fell early, how do we know that the new month that just preceded the equinox was not declared a leap month? Wouldn't March 10 be too early for the barley harvest? If not, then March 10 would be declared Nisan 1. But if it wasn't, then March 10 would be the first day of Adar II in 34 CE.

Here is a link to the Rosetta Calendar. You can search for Julian Calendar dates, Gregorian Calendar dates, and even the Jewish dates at Jesus time. But the Rosetta Calendar warns you that the Hebrew Calendar could be off by as little as two days and by as much as a month. That's because the Jewish dates have been computed mathematically backwards in time using the Jewish method of calculating their calendar. In Jesus day, the calendar did not go by these dates. Remember that the months began by observation, not calculation. And the decision to add an extra month was not done by calculation as it is today but by whether it was too early in the year for the barley to ripen. Don't forget if the barley wouldn't ripen until April, an extra month would be added at that time. Under today's Jewish calculation of their calendar, seven leap years occur every 19 years. The 19 year span is called the Metonic Cycle. Leap years occur every third, sixth, eighth, eleventh, fourteenth, seventeenth, and nineteenth years of the cycle.

https://www.rosettacalendar.com/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle

The Rosetta Calendar website compares the Julian, Gregorian, and Jewish Calendar and you can check what day of the week and what date a certain day fell on. However, they offer a disclaimer on their Jewish Calendar results.

Warning: This calendar was observation-based in ancient times. Using this website's formual-based calendar for biblical dates can give results that are off by several days up to more than a month.

This disclaimer is necessary because in ancient Israel the months were not calculated to the day of the new moon as it is today but was established by observation. The first day of the month was determined by observation. When the thin crescent of the moon was observed in the western sky at sunset, that evening would be declared day one.

The first day of the first month was set usually when the Barley harvest was ripe or about ripe. If it would be ripe within two weeks, the month would begin. If, however, the barley wasn't ripe or wouldn't be in two weeks an extra month would be added.

Comment: "Pilate was the governor of Judah" No, he wasn't. He was prefect of Judea. That's not the same. As you ask a question about pinpoint precision, you should rephrase this.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear why we would care?  I'm not challenging, I'm just not sure I understand the implications of the question. I can't imagine any way this would help me to understand history.

Comment: I wonder if any research has been done as to when the barley harvest most likely fell in each of the relevant years. For example might tree rings or similar data give some clue, or Nile flood records? Or how well is the climate of those years understood? Was it a warm or cold period across the Mediteranean generally?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, we cannot be sure for the Jewish calendar because it depended on the sighting of the new moon with which weather conditions regularly interfered. There is also a dispute about whether the first of Nissan was calculated from the barley harvest or the equinox.

For example, here is one way to do the calculation, but not all will agree.

**Jesus' Baptism**

The beginning of Jesus’ ministry was marked by His baptism and anointing by the Holy Spirit, which, according to Luke 3:1 occurred in the 15th year of the reign of Tiberius Caesar.  Unlike the Persian calendar, the Jews in New Testament times used the non-accession year dating, or inclusive reckoning.  This means that when a monarch ascended the throne, the first incomplete calendar year (no matter how small) was counted as the first year.  Since Tiberius ascended the imperial throne on 19 August 14 AD, his “fifteenth year” would be the twelve months beginning 1 Ethanim (September/October) 27 AD by the non-accession reckoning of the Jews.  Since Jesus’ ministry lasted 3½ years according to the Gospel record (see below for this date), Jesus’ Baptism occurred about October/November, 27 AD.

There is further evidence of this date.  Luke also records that Jesus was baptized when He was “about 30 years old” (Luke 3:23).  While the exact date of Jesus’ birth is unknown, there is a narrow range from which to choose.  It was after the Caesar Augustus’ census of 8 BC which took several years to complete.  And, it was before Herod’s death in April 4 BC.  Since shepherds were in the fields, Jesus must have been born before Nov 5 BC and probably about Sep/Oct 5 BC.  In Oct 27 AD, He would have been 31 years old, or “about 30 years old”.  Later dates suggested by some would stretch the meaning of Luke’s age too far.

**Jesus' Crucifixion**

Jesus’ death on 14th of Nissan.  The usual dating systems require finding a year in the range 30 AD to 33 AD in which the Jewish Passover fell on Friday.  Since we do not have definitive and precise information about the Jewish calendar (specifically the occurrence of “leap years” with the second Adar), such methods depend more on what is unknown than known.  Even astronomical methods cannot help because they depend upon local meteorological conditions such as cloud obscuring a new moon.  However, the overwhelming consensus from such methods, despite their limitations suggests that the crucifixion must have occurred during the Passover in Nisan (March/April), either in March, 30 AD, or, April, 31 AD.  The former is too early as already shown (Jesus’ ministry lasted more than 2½ years), but the second accords with the known facts.

Despite the insuperable difficulties in knowing the local calendar of 2000 years ago, there are still a very limited range of possible dates from which to choose.  If we accept that Jesus died on the afternoon of Friday, 14th of Nisan, then the first of Nisan must be at sunset on Friday, about 18:00 local time.  In the years 30-33, there are only two years that are even possible, namely,

- 30 AD when New Moon occurs at 20:07, Wed, Mar 22 local time.  Thus, Nisan 1 would begin about 1 day and 22 hours later on Mar 24.  This accords with the Babylonian calendar (not used in Jerusalem) but such an event is almost too soon in date and too soon after sunset to be reliably seen.
- 31 AD when New Moon occurs at 13:53, Tues, Apr 10 local time.  Thus, Nisan 1 would begin about 3 days and 4 hours later on Apr 17.  This is more credible.

Comment: I like this answer. I was hoping to come up with  a sure fire way to calculate the beginning of the month the month Jesus died but as you pointed out, since the new moon was not when Israel began their month, but the first sighting of the crescent moon. Also, I was hoping to find whether the first day of the year was when the barley harvest was going to be ripe on Passover week or whether if the new month could begin if the vernal equinox had not happened yet. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> ...the bottom line is he was "about" 30 when he was baptized. Could
> that mean he was 29 going on 30 or he was just turned 31?

Lk 3:23 means Jesus was from 26 to 34 years old at the time of his Baptism.

> Now, how long did his ministry last?

It depends on the dates of his Baptism and Crucifixion. Hypothesized lengths range from little more than 1 year (Jan 29 - Apr 30) to little more than 5 years (Jan 28 - Apr 33).

Focusing on the dating of the beginning of the ministry of John the Baptist "in the fifteenth year of the hegemonias of Tiberius Caesar" (Lk 3:1), there are several dating methods that Luke may have followed according to the following tree of choices:

1st choice: type of regnal years:

- D. factual a.k.a. Dynastic regnal years,
- C. Calendrical regnal years.

Within D: event marking the beginning of Tiberius' reign:

- D.13. Granting of proconsular power co-extensive with Augustus', i.e. including Rome, on 27 June 13,
- D.14. Augustus' death on 19 August 14.

Within C: 3 independent binary choices:

- between the event marking the beginning of Tiberius' reign (as in D),
- between accession year and non-accession year (aka inclusive) reckoning,
- between the Syro-Macedonian and the Jewish calendar,

plus an additional binary choice in the case of the Jewish calendar:

- between the year beginning on Tishrei 1 as used by the Diaspora and the year beginning on Nisan 1 as used in the Second Temple.

Therefore there are 14 possible combinations in total, 2 within branch D and 12 within branch C, the latter group comprising 4 under the Syro-Macedonian calendar and 8 under the Jewish calendar. Of those 14 combinations:

- 2 are compatible with Jesus' Baptism in January 27,
- 8 are compatible with Jesus' Baptism in January 28 (they include the above 2),
- 13 are compatible with Jesus' Baptism in January 29 (they include the above 8), and
- 1 is compatible only with Jesus' Baptism in January 30, which is discarded.

> how do we determine the year Jesus died if we know he died on a
> Friday, Nisan 14 and was raised from the dead Sunday, Nisan 16?

By looking at the dates of the pre-Nisan new moons. But first I have to broaden your question, because it is assuming Johannine cronology of the Passion, which is not the only possibility (though it is the one I hold):

```
According to - Jesus died - So that Nisan 1
               on Friday  - would have been a

the Synoptics - Nisan 15 - Friday

John's gospel - Nisan 14 - Saturday
```

Before the IV century CE the Jewish calendar was observational, with a court proclaiming the 1st day of each month (Rosh Chodesh) on the basis of witnesses reporting the sighting of the new crescent moon. Specifically, in the morning of the (provisionally) day 30 of the ending month the court assembled and waited for witnesses. If during the day the required number of qualifying witnesses testified to having seen the new crescent shortly after the previous sunset, then the court proclaimed that the ongoing day was in fact the 1st day of the new month. If no witness appeared then the ongoing day was confirmed as day 30 of the ending month and the next day was proclaimed as the 1st day of the new month without necessity of witnesses, since a lunar month can have only 29 or 30 days.

Since astronomical computations determine the date and time of the new moon (the conjunction) but the beginning of the month was decided on the basis of the first sighting of the new crescent, we have to link new moon with first visibility, which is an active field of research because the islamic calendar is still observational. I will bring into consideration only two pieces of information which are relevant for the purposes of this answer.

First, "the 'best time' for the first visibility of the thin crescent moon is directly proportional to site elevation", so that "at a site elevation of 1000 m or less [such as in Jerusalem, which is at 754 m above sea level] the crescent could be first seen 5 to 10 minutes after sunset" [1].

Thus, using from now on Israel **Standard** Time (**IST** = GMT + 2), we have for Jerusalem in the interval of interest, taking sunset times from [2]:

```
Day:                         Mar 6  Mar 20 Apr 4

Jerusalem sunset time (IST): 17:40  17:50  18:00

Best time for 1st sighting:  17:50  18:00  18:10
```

This is confirmed by the times of the first sightings in [3].

Second, the historical record for the shortest time between new moon and first sighting with the naked eye is 15.0 hours [4]. To note, this sighting did not happen by chance but **as a result of an specific expedition for that purpose by a party of six amateur astronomers**. Quoting from [4]:

> John Pierce [...] has had previous experience at crescent watching.
> [...] The observers pre-calculated the position of the Moon (with
> respect to the sunset point) for a specific time so that they knew
> exactly where to look. Pierce spotted the Moon with the unaided eye,
> and the sighting was confirmed with a 12.5-inch telescope as seen by
> four people. Jan Kemp also saw the Moon with aneided vision, Clint
> Bach and Ed Byrd saw the crescent only through binoculars and the
> telescope, while Jim Golden and Travis Byrd could not see the Moon at
> all.

Therefore if a new moon occurred during Julian/Gregorian date N (delimited in Roman day reckoning, from midnight to midnight), then:

- The most probable time of 1st sighting of the new crescent is shortly after sunset of Julian/Gregorian date N+1.
- A 1st sigthing shortly after sunset of the same day N is theoretically possible, but extremely unlikely, if the new moon occurred before 03:00 IST (in March). This is so because the historical record for the shortest time between new moon and first sighting with the naked eye is 15.0 hours [4].
- A 1st sigthing shortly after sunset of day N+2 is possible if the new moon occurred after 12:00 IST (in March), given that moon ages at first sigthings can be over 50 hours [4]. The probability of such late sighting increases as the new moon time gets closer to 24:00.

With the above in mind, let's examine the pre-Nisan new moons of 29-34, taking new moon data from [5] (adding 02:00 to convert GMT to IST) and weekdays from [6]:

```
Year  Pre-Nisan - Most/Next probable    - Consequent Nisan 1
      new moon  - new crescent sighting - time span and weekday
      (IST)       (IST)

29   Apr 02 19:30 - Apr 03 18:10 - Apr 03 sunset - Apr 04 sunset, Monday

     late sighting  Apr 04 18:10 - Apr 04 sunset - Apr 05 sunset, Tuesday

30   Mar 22 19:47 - Mar 23 18:00 - Mar 23 sunset - Mar 24 sunset, Friday

     late sighting  Mar 24 18:00 - Mar 24 sunset - Mar 25 sunset, Saturday

31   Mar 12 00:20 - Mar 13 17:55 - Mar 13 sunset - Mar 14 sunset, Wednesday

     early sighting Mar 12 17:55 - Mar 12 sunset - Mar 13 sunset, Tuesday

31e  Apr 10 13:33 - Apr 11 18:15 - Apr 11 sunset - Apr 12 sunset, Thursday
                    
32   Mar 29 22:01 - Mar 30 18:05 - Mar 30 sunset - Mar 31 sunset, Monday

     late sighting  Mar 31 18:05 - Mar 31 sunset - Apr 01 sunset, Tuesday

33   Mar 19 12:39 - Mar 20 18:00 - Mar 20 sunset - Mar 21 sunset, Saturday

34   Mar  9 05:27 - Mar 10 17:55 - Mar 10 sunset - Mar 11 sunset, Thursday

34e  Apr  7 13:43 - Apr 08 18:10 - Apr 08 sunset - Apr 09 sunset, Friday
```

The entries YYe cover the (IMO unlikely) cases in which the ending year was embolismic.

Thus, the open possibilities are:

```
In year:  Jesus' could have been crucified according to the date in:

  30    either the Synoptics or John's Gospel
  33    John's Gospel
  34    the Synoptics
```

**References**

[1] Sultan, Abdul Haq. "'Best time'for the visibility of the lunar crescent." *The Observatory*, Vol. 126, pp. 115-118 (2006).
https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2006Obs...126..115S

[2] https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/israel/jerusalem

[3] Hoffman, Roy E. "Observing the new Moon." *Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society*, Vol. 340, Issue 3, pp. 1039–1051 (2003).
https://doi.org/10.1046/j.1365-8711.2003.06382.x

[4] Schaefer, Bradley E. "Lunar crescent visibility." *Quarterly Journal of the Royal Astronomical Society*, Vol. 37, p. 759 (1996).
https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1996QJRAS..37..759S

[5] Fred Espenak, "Six Millennium Catalog of Phases of the Moon".
1 to 100 AD: http://astropixels.com/ephemeris/phasescat/phases0001.html

[6] https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/calendar/

Comment: Internet historian and author Daniel Gregg has written a book on the subject of Jesus's death and resurrection. He has done a great deal of work in chronology and he places Jesus's death in March 34 CE. I think the date he gave was March 24, 34 CE on Nisan 14, I can't remember the exact date from the Julian Calendar but it seemed it occurred just a few days after the vernal equinox. He claims Jesus's ministry was a little over five Passovers.

Comment: Though it is not my personal opinion, entry 34e, implying Crucifixion on April 23, 34 CE, agrees with the visions of Maria Valtorta. https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=122607

Comment: Another researcher who claims Jesus' ministry was a little over 5 Passovers is Bill Heroman. http://www.billheroman.com/p/timeline-of-new-testament-events.html